# Run OSQL on systems which do not have Sql Server installed

Tags: sql-server, odbc, osql

I have a batch file which runs an oSQL command (below).

```
oSQL -U devUID -P testPwd -S testServer -d testDb  -Q "EXEC [dbo].[sprocTEST]"
```

When I run this batch file on systems which do not have sqlserver installed, it throws an error.

"odbc driver manager data source name not found and no default driver specified osql"

NOTE: Apart from the batch file I also copied - osql.exe , osql.rll

Does any one know how to resolve the odbc driver error?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the rights to redistribute `osql.exe` nor `osql.rll`, so you cannot copy them. The computer must install the SQL Server client tools from a valid distribution source, or you're breaking the law. The ODBC drivers are installed by [MDAC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en).